Proving $\lim_{y\to 0} y^2 \ln|yx^2|=0$ using sequences

I have the function
$$f(x, y) =  y^2 \ln|yx^2|$$ and I want to prove that $f(x, 0)$ goes to zero but using sequences.

SO I thought about this: I choose $b_n = \frac{1}{n}$, and in general any $b_n$ with the conditions that $b_n \neq 0$ and $b_n \to 0$ as $n\to +\infty$. In this way
$$f(x, b_n) = \frac{1}{n^2} \ln\bigg\vert\frac{x^2}{n}\bigg\vert$$
Now this goes to zero since I can split the logarithm into $\ln(x^2) + \ln|1/n|$ and each term goes to zero (the first one is trivial, since $x \neq 0$ and the second one can be viewed as infinities hierarchy, or passing into $\mathbb{R}$ and using Hopital Theorem or else).
But my question is: is this enough? Because what I actually shown is that this goes to zero with a particular sequence.

How can I prove that this holds "for every" sequence that respects the two conditions above?

Thank you!
(On the other side, this doesn't work with $f(a_n, y)$, where here any choice for $a_n$ should make $f(0, y) \to \infty$).

BTW, '$f(x, 0)$ goes to zero' has no meaning, but I am guessing that you want to prove $f(x,b) \to f(x,0)$ as $ b \to 0+$.

$f(x,y)$ is not defined (as a real number) for $y<0$.

@geetha290krm Yes, I am an idiot. I just noticed I wrote wrong. There is an absolute value in the function... Blimey! Going to edit.

There is no difference between the proofs for the  particular sequence $(b_n)$ and a general one: $b_n^{2}\ln (|b_n|x^{2})=b_n^{2}\ln |b_n|+b_n^{2}\ln (x^{2})$ and each of the two terms tends to $0$. [Recall that $t \ln t \to $ as $t \to0+$].

Oh, well... It was just this in the end. I thought it was more complicated. Thank you!
